# How to modify a Clef rule to approve Ethereum requests based on specific miner and IP address?

Tags: go-ethereum, geth-clique

How can I modify my Clef rule to approve requests based on both a specific miner and a specific IP address in Ethereum?

Here is my current code, which approves requests from a specific miner:

```
function ApproveTx(req) {
    if (req.transaction.to.toLowerCase() == "0xae967917c465db8578ca9024c205720b1a3651a9") {
        return "Approve"
    }
}
```

What additional condition can I add to the if statement to approve requests only if they are sent from a specific IP address?

Also, I would like to know if there is a documentation or a way to print the functions and variables of the req parameter.

Answer (score 0):

When I print the req object, I got the following information:

```
{
  "transaction": {
    "from": "0xB30eAE1448a6DeC2D...",
    "to": "0xB30EAe1448A6DEc2D1E...",
    "gas": "0x5208",
    "gasPrice": "0x3b9aca00",
    "maxFeePerGas": null,
    "maxPriorityFeePerGas": null,
    "value": "0x1bc16d674ec80000",
    "nonce": "0x9",
    "data": "0x",
    "chainId": "0x4deb"
  },
  "call_info": null,
  "meta": {
    "remote": "ipaddress",
    "local": "ipAddress",
    "scheme": "ipc",
    "User-Agent": "",
    "Origin": ""
  }
}
```

So I updated the rules to be like the following:

```
function ApproveTx(req) {
  const remoteIp = req.meta.remote.split(":")[0];
  if (req.transaction.to.toLowerCase() == "0xae967917c465db8578ca9024c205720b1a3651a9" && remoteIp == '159...') {
    return "Approve"
  }
  return 'Reject';
}
```